# Имею ли я право на использование JDK в своём продукте?

Tags: openjdk, лицензирование

Всем привет, вопрос такой. Я разрабатываю IDE с использованием JDK. Имею ли я право так делать? Мне надо спросить у пользователя принять лицензионное соглашение? Где его взять, как подать?

Comment: JDK ведь сам по себе бесплатный, даже некоторая часть под GPL лицензией.
Думаю вы ничего не нарушаете, используя JDK в своем проекте. У вас IDE будет бесплатной? Или коммерческой?

Comment: @SoftQualityRC, free и pro версии

Comment: а что вам мешаете написать в сам oracle и спросить у поддержки. За free версию все и так ясно, никто с вас не спросит. А вот за pro стоит немного задуматься. В принципе если вы прикрутите в лицензионное соглашение отрывок из oracl-а, хуже не будет. Там где про использование двоичного кода.

Comment: @SoftQualityRC, понял, спасибо за совет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Вопросы о лицензировании и распространении](https://www.java.com/ru/download/faq/distribution.xml)

[Официальная лицензия на сайте Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html)

**Да, программное обеспечение Java можно распространять вместе с разработанным вами программным обеспечением при условии соблюдения положений и условий лицензионного соглашения о распространении двоичного кода Java.**

Программное обеспечение Java можно распространять на компакт-дисках cреди пользователей организации. Кроме того, вы вправе включать Java в состав разрабатываемых вами приложений и распространять их в едином пакете за пределами вашей организации. Распространение программного обеспечения Java на компакт-дисках за пределами организации без включения его в состав разрабатываемых вами приложений запрещено.

Comment: тоесть, как я понял, в моем случае, я должен перед тем как пускать пользователя в IDE, спросить у него принять лицензионного соглашения (вторая ссылка в вашем ответе)

Comment: а есть ли разница в соглашении в бесплатной и платной версиях моего продукта?

Comment: Конечно есть разница, даже не знаю куда вам копать подсказать. По поводу написания лицензионного соглашения. 
Ваш продукт имеет по сути две версии, с бесплатной вопросов нет. В платной соглашение должно быть другим однозначно. При том, к примеру у вас будет подписка (вы должны это все упоминать). А если пользователь решит отказаться от вашего продукта и начнёт требовать возврат средств? Учитывайте все детали, ЛС - это достаточно важный момент, он поможет вам сберечь в будущем нервы и время.

Comment: ок, пусть пока что бесплатно все будет) как надумаю выпустить про-версию спрошу у Oracle поподробнее

Comment: Отличное решение! Поддерживайте комьюнити open source!